# Не отправляется сообщение на емейл в PHP

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, вот изучаю ПХП и написал опросник небольшой и необходимо чтобы при его прохождении отправлялось письмо на емейл с данными которые человек ввёл в опросе. 
Структура следующая:

Сама форма в HTML:

```
<form name="oprosnik" action="mail.php" method="post">
<div><b>Введите Ф И О:</b>
    <div><input type="text" name="fio" /></div>
    </div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Вопросы:</b></div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><b>Вы:</b> 
    Мужчина<input type=radio name="sex" value="man"> 
    Женщина<input type=radio name="sex" value="woman"></div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">  
<b>На чём вы собираетесь играть в GTA 5?</b><br>
<input type=radio name="console" value="PS"> На PlayStation 3<br>
<input type=radio name="console" value="XBOX"> На XBOX 360<br>
<input type=radio name="console" value="PC"> На PC<br>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">  
<b>Оцените игру:</b><br>
<input type=radio name="rait" value="1"> Очень плохо<br>
<input type=radio name="rait" value="3"> Не надо<br>
<input type=radio name="rait" value="5"> Общепит<br>
<input type=radio name="rait" value="7"> В самый раз<br>
<input type=radio name="rait" value="9"> Очень круто<br>
<input type=radio name="rait" value="10"> ШЕДЕВР!<br>
</div>

<div><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /> <input type="reset" value="Сбросить"/></div>
</form>
```

И собственно вот как я всё описал в ПХП.

```
    <?php
if($_POST['oprosnik']) {

    $fio = ($_POST['fio']);
    $sex = ($_GET['sex']);
    $console = ($_GET['console']);
    $rait = ($_GET['rait']);

    $to = "some_mail@mail.ru";
    $subject = "Robot - Робот";
    $message = "<html><head></head><body> 
                На сайте ответили на вопросы! <br><br> 
                <table width=100% border=0> 
                <tr><td width=10></td> 
                <td><b>".$fio."</b><br>".$sex." <br> ".$console"<br> ".$rait" 
                </td> 
                </tr></table><br> 
                </body></html>";
    $headers = "From: keh192.bget.ru <abc@gmail.com>\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
    mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Письмо на почту не приходит... Если же написать просто уведомление вот в таком виде:

```
<?php
  $to = "some_mail@mail.ru";
  $subject = "Robot - Робот";
  $message = "Message,\n сообщение!";
  $headers = "From: keh192.bget.ru <abc@gmail.com>\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
  mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

То всё прекрасно приходит. В чём моя ошибка? мб я где то описал не так переменные или не выбираются необходимые данный и скрипт даёт сбой? 
ПХП начал изучать 3 дня назад, очень нужна помощь в данном вопросе. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Во-первых:**
oprosnik не будет отправлен, а значит условие `if($_POST['oprosnik'])` никогда не будет выполнено.
Проведите простой эксперимент:

```
<form name="form" action="thisfile.php" method=post>
    <input name="button" type=submit value=ok />
</form>

<?
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Результат:

```
array(1) { ["button"]=> string(2) "ok" }
```

**Во-вторых**
у Вас непонятная смесь из `$_POST` и `$_GET`. Вам это не кажется неправильным? У Вас форма POST, а пытаетесь данные Вы получить из GET.

Comment: @ReinRaus, я убрал условие, поменял методы везде на POST, прописал шапки, получился вот такой ПХП документ:

Comment: <?php
 $fio = ($_POST['fio']);
 $sex = ($_POST['sex']);
 $console = ($_POST['console']);
 $rait = ($_POST['rait']);

 $to = "keh192@mail.ru";
 $subject = "Robot - Робот";
 $message = "<html><head></head><body> 
    На сайте ответили на вопросы! <br><br> 
    <table width=100% border=0> 
    <tr><td width=10></td> 
    <td><b>".$fio."</b><br>".$sex." <br> ".$console"<br> ".$rait" 
    </td> 
    </tr></table><br> 
    </body></html>";
 $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: Но всё равно почта не приходит, где я еще ошибся?

Comment: @KeH192, может из-за того, что пропущены операторы конкатенации (точки) в строке:  

     <td><b>".$fio."</b><br>".$sex." <br> ".$console"<br> ".$rait"
должно быть:  

    <td><b>".$fio."</b><br>".$sex." <br> ".$console."<br> ".$rait."

Comment: @ReinRaus, действительно! всё заработало! Спасибо вам большое! Пойду дальше изучать ПХП!))

Answer (score 0):

Возможно необходимо изменить Content-type на text/html
так как текст у вас нормально уходит, а html нет.

Comment: неправильный content-type не является поводом не отправить сообщение, правда в спам попасть может.

Answer (score 0):

/ *Для отправки HTML-почты вы можете установить шапку Content-type.* /

```
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

/ *дополнительные шапки* /

```
$headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";
```

/ *и теперь отправим из* /

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Ссылка на материал  http://www.php.su/functions/?mail