# Нужно отправить данные из формы на сайте на адрес электронной почты

Tags: php, html

Есть простая форма с требованием имейла. Нужно, чтобы эти данные с нее отправлялись на мой имейл. Как это реализовать? Уверен, это не сложно, просто нужно знать как. Спасибо!

```
   <div class="w-form">
            <form action="send.php" class="email-address w-clearfix" data-name="Email Form" id="mc_embed_signup" method="post" name="email-form"><input class="email-address w-input" data-name="Email" id="Email-Address" maxlength="256" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required="required" type="email"><input class="button w-button" data-wait="Please wait..." type="submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Верхняяформа', 'submit')" value="Start playing today"></form>
            <div class="success-message-2 w-form-done">
              <div>Thank you! Please check your email now.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-form-fail">
              <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

UP

Создал send.php, но не работает. Открывается страница с символами и все на этом. Что не так?

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to = "pianoforall.lessons@gmail.com"; //куда отправлять письмо
$subject = "Новый"; //тема
$message = 'Имейл: '.$_POST['email'].';';
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: <news@new-pianoforall.com>\r\n";
$result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($result){
    echo "Cообщение успешно отправленно. Пожалуйста, оставайтесь на связи";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Вы смотрели тысячу похожих вопросов на данном сайте прежде чем писать вопрос?

Comment: Да. Но мне ничего не понятнто. Думал помогут тут

Comment: [отправка письма на почту php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575880/191482) - по-моему вполне  .......[Не отправляется сообщение на емейл в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/284378/191482) - без ajax уже готовый пример прям в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Я бревно в этом, поэтому если вопросы тупые, то сорян. А с какого адреса оно будет приходить? Я суть уловил, но не понял, где в этом коде строка отвечающая за отравку самого имейла?

<?php
  $to = "some_mail@mail.ru";
  $subject = "Robot - Робот";
  $message = "Message,\n сообщение!";
  $headers = "From: keh192.bget.ru <abc@gmail.com>\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
  mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: `mail(....` - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php

Comment: Я не программист и уже запутался с этим в край( Можно конкретно на моем примере показать? 1.Есть код моей формы. 2. Затем мне нужно создать php отладчик. Создал, но не работает. У вас есть возможность отправить этот код? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score -1):

Если хостинг не отключил функцию mail(), то попробуйте через неё (пример https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/48759/)
А если всё таки эта функция отключена используйте smtp сервисы

Comment: Раздел с электронной почтой там есть, а название какое должно быть у этой функции? Спасибо!